# Save multiple excel sheets in a random order to a single pdf document

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have an Excel file with about a dozen sheets/tabs. About three of the finalized sheets/tabs out of those dozen tabs go to a single PDF for the reporting purposes. Right now I have a macro doing that for me, it also saves it with the desired file name.

However, the macro saves the tabs/sheets to the PDF in the order in which these appear in the Excel file. But I want to assign a random order to the sheets going in into the PDF report. And I can not change the order of the Excel sheets for reasons internal to our organization.

Can anybody suggest some lines of code I could do to assign a manual/random order to my sheets? The code I currently use for exporting multiple selected sheets to PDF is as follows:

```
Sub Save_as_pdf()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim s(1) As String
Dim sNewFilePath As String
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    s(0) = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    If FSO.FileExists(s(0)) Then
        s(1) = FSO.GetExtensionName(s(0))
        If s(1) <> "" Then
            s(1) = "." & s(1)
            sNewFilePath = Replace(s(0), s(1), ".pdf")
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            Filename:=sNewFilePath, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        End If
        Else
    End If
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Even though you say you can't change the order, I think that's the way to go. No need to save it afterwards. Or work with a temporary copy.